# Python Pandas - how to sum elements of an array which appears in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Data Frame:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([(1, 2, [1, 2, 3, 4]),  \
                    (1, 2, [5, 6, 7, 8])], \
                    columns = ['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

I want to sum the elements of the arrays of column 'c' so that their sum in each row will appear in a new column 'd'.
But `df1['d'] = df1['c'].sum` yields the following result:

```
   a  b             c                                                  d
0  1  2  [1, 2, 3, 4]  <bound method Series.sum of 0    [1, 2, 3, 4]\...
1  1  2  [5, 6, 7, 8]  <bound method Series.sum of 0    [1, 2, 3, 4]\...
```

instead of:

```
     a  b              c    d
  0  1  2   [1, 2, 3, 4]    10
  1  1  2   [5, 6, 7, 8]    26
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`sum` is a function, so you'd need parenthesis (although the approach was not correct anyways, since you'd have to `apply` the function in question here). Being a `pd.Series` `map` is enough:

```
df1['d'] = df1.c.map(sum)

print(df1)

   a  b             c   d
0  1  2  [1, 2, 3, 4]  10
1  1  2  [5, 6, 7, 8]  26
```

Answer (score 0):

This should also work :

```
df1['d'] = df1['c'].apply(lambda x: sum(x))
```